# variable in PDDL that can be of more than one type?

Tags: planning, pddl

Is there any version of this statement that is valid, expressing that an actor knows another actor or a location? Or must I specify separate predicates knows_actor and knows_location?

```
 (:predicates     
    (knows     ?a - ACTOR ?thing - ACTOR LOCATION)
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the planner you are using supports types, a possible simple solution is to define a supertype in the types section:

```
ACTOR LOCATON - ACTOR_OR_LOCATION
```

and then define the second parameter of the predicate (**?thing**) with the type **ACTOR_OR_LOCATION**

Comment: Yes, that works. I've seen this also done by setting specific types (ACTOR, LOCATION) also to the catchall type OBJECT.